# Super Search and Stash and limiting results

Tags: stash, supersearch, tags

I am going to try my best to explain what I am trying to accomplish so I will be breaking this up into various parts.

WHAT I AM TRYING TO ACCOMPLISH:

Create a filtered list of search results into various lists. For example I want my filtered results to end up in SECTION A, SECTION B, SECTION C and so on. I will probably have 5 sections once all said and done.

Within each section I only want 3 articles to appear. I will then have a view more button to take the user to see a larger selection of entries.

HOW I AM SEARCHING MY CONTENT:

I currently have used Solspace's Tag module and tagged my articles as needed.

I then have a Super Search form searching my tags using checkboxes.

Then on my search result page I am using Stash to help me organize my entries into SECTION A, SECTION B and so on.

This is working as expected!

WHAT I AM HAVING ISSUES WITH:

My main issue at this point in time is limiting my search results per SECTION A, SECTION B and so on. I can limit my results per Super Search but that limit effects all sections meaning that I can only have 3 entries displaying across all SECTIONS combined. What I need is a total of 3 entries to be shown in each SECTION. I hope this makes sense.

Below is my sample code for my checkbox in the search form:

```
<label> &lt;input type="checkbox" name="our_tags[]" value="reg-link" {if super_search_our_tags_reg-link}checked="checked"{/if}&gt; Regional/Community Links </label>
```

Then in my search results page I have the following:

```
{exp:stash:set name="service-results" parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:super_search:results channel="test" search_in="priority_tags|our_tags" orderby="test+desc+priority_tags+desc" search="limit=3"} 
        {exp:tag:tags entry_id="{entry_id}"} 
            {if {tag_id} == "21"} 
                <div style="background-color:#efefef"> 
                <h3>{title}</h3> 
                <p>Our Tags - {our_tags}</p> 
                <p>Priority Tags - {priority_tags}</p> 
                <p><a href="{path='articles/by_tag'}/tag/{websafe_tag}">{tag}</a>, </p> 
                <p><strong>{search_excerpt}</strong></p>     </div> 
           {/if} 
       {/exp:tag:tags} 
    {/exp:super_search:results} 
{/exp:stash:set}
```

I display my Stash output like so:

```
{exp:stash:get name="service-results"}
```

I have also attached a screen shot of my checkboxes and of the search result area. I hope these help explain a little more what I am trying to accomplish.

Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated! 
If I need to provide additional information please let me know.

Thanks in advance,

John

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Ended up creating tags for each of the form areas. Then using a jquery plug-in to help load in my information via ajax.